# Need some help, anyone know why system sound isn't working on iPad but is on iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, ios, avfoundation

I am working on an app for kids, and I am using short audio with the AVFoundation framework and AudioServicesCreateSystemSound.  The app works great with no issues on iPhone 3, 3G, 4, 4s.  However it isn't working on an iPad 2 ill put the code for playing the sound with, I'm just not sure if there is an issue with it on the iPad or what, it works fine in the simulator for the iPad but not on the actual device.  The code is below:

```
-(IBAction)soundcar {
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"auto", CFSTR("wav"), NULL);

    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

anyone know what I can do to fix, it would be great or if it may be just an issue with the iPad itself I'm not sure.  Anything that helps is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Stupid question I know, but the volume is not down on the device is it? You'd be amazed how many times we see this....

Comment: No the volume is not down and the silence is not on, I double checked I am thinking that the iPad is not compatible with AudioServicesCreateSystemSound and will most likely switch to the AVFoundation playAudio but wanted to know if anyone knew if that was the case before I made the change.

Comment: I got the audio to playback for the iPad however the volume of the playback is extremely low and almost inaudible.  I had the iPad at max volume, the way I have it coded works great on iPhone/iPod but for some reason the audio is coming out too low on the iPad, if there are any suggestions or if anyone else came across this problem any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found what the problem was, on iPad and possibly iPod the ringers and alert volume is default to a low setting, turning this volume up fixes the audio volume output for createSystemSound.